# Discord tag regular expression validation Google Forms

Tags: regex, discord, google-forms

Is there any way you can use a regular expression in Google Forms to check if their input matches a pattern for a Discord tag? I already tried this: `#[0-9]{4}$`, but that's only valid for input that starts with a '#' followed by 4 numeric digits. I know this regex (next line) works for Discord tags, maybe there is a way to convert that to a regular expression in Google Forms?

```regex
/^((.+?)#\d{4})/
```

A Discord tag is constructed by their username followed by an '#' and then finished with 4 numbers. A few examples are:

- Anna#1234
- Bob#5601
- Ryan Peterson#5640

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share some test data so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos, what additional info would you like?

Comment: *"what additional info would you like?"* Not every reader is aware of the pattern of a Discord tag. So. What does a Discord tag might look like? Please edit your question and  give some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** *(following OP's [revised question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66471126/revisions))*

You can also use the following

```
.+#\d{4}
```

---

As mentioned on [The Discord Wiki](https://discordia.me/en/discord-tag)

> A "Discord tag" is the combination of a username and their discriminator (a 4-digit number). The tag always appears as `username#discriminator`.

**Not all regular expressions are supported in Google Forms validation.**
In this case the regular expression *(regex)* you should use is

```
.+\d{4}$
```

[image]